# substring on html.encode

Tags: c#, substring

how can I limit the # of characters to display for html.encode?

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.LastName.Substring(1,30))%>
```

error: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: We're not automatic syntax highlighters to determine which language is it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check the strings length is greater than 30, otherwise you are specifying a length which will fall off the end of the string...(I've also changed your start index to 0 assuming you didn't mean to leave out the first character)

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.LastName.Substring(0, 
                     item.LastName.Length > 30 ? 30 : item.LastName.Length))%>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could also do something like

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.LastName.Substring(0, Math.Min(item.LastName.Length, 30)) %>
```

to save some bytes

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.LastName.Substring(0, item.LastName.Length > 30 ? 30 : item.LastName.Length))%>
```

If you want to check for null, do this instead:

```
<%= Html.Encode(
item.LastName == null ? string.Empty :
item.LastName.Substring(0, item.LastName.Length > 30 ? 30 : item.LastName.Length))%>
```

Comment: Indexes are 0 based, while .Length is 1 based.  >= won't work in this case.  Use > instead.

Comment: Thanks folks for all of the replies.  Pardon me but what if the string is null?